# How to create a meetup at a chosen city? (And how to delete erroneous entries?)

Tags: support, community, meetups

I would like to participate at the [Worldwide MeetUp Day](http://www.meetup.com/stackoverflow/).

For Belgium, the system lists Geel, Wetteren and Liège, but I'd like to meet up in, for example, Brussels (the capital). How can I meet up in a city of my choice?

As suggested in a now deleted answer, I tried the following, given the explanation "Enter the name of your neighborhood, town, or city":

[image: Mockup of create new community]

However, after entering "Brussels" this does not allow one to pick a location on the map. The title of the new meetup also remains Liège, Belgium, and there is no way to remove it. So, http://meetup.com/stackoverflow/Brussels is wrong now.

Comment: Which city would that be?

Comment: @What, info (if correct) is in his profile.

Comment: @tom but that's not necessarily the one that he is talking about.

Comment: @What: Brussels, which is both in the French community and the capital of Flemish region. All cities proposed are either in Flemish or French regions. (yeah, Region & community is different, it's complicated)

Comment: @Pierre I assume you have to sign up with meetup and will be presented the possibility when logged in.

Comment: @Arjan: did the same

Comment: @Pierre303, this happened because in your screenshot it says "Start a new community in Liège, Belgium", so it is a new community, but still with that as its main location.  I've deleted this community for you, and @badp got you the rest of the way there. (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a search box near the top. It accepts "any" city, allowing you to create meetups in an arbitrary city if you really must :)

Comment: Wow, you're right, that is one confusing interface! It seemed that typing a random city name did not give me any special results, but indeed the "Start a new community in [...]" thingy changes into the town one has searched for.

Comment: Excellent ! It worked perfectly

Comment: Any chance you know how to delete erroneous entries? (Or even just rename them?)

Comment: @Arjan No idea.